# Add two complex numbers - preserving non-principal angle value

Tags: complex-numbers

In control theory, complex numbers are used to represent the response of a system at various frequencies.

E.g.

```
H(s)=s^2
```

is a cascaded differentiator.  Its phase frequency response is $\angle\pi$ rad at all frequencies.

Further, consider this transfer function:

```
H(s)=s^5
```

This TF represents a cascade of five differentiators.  The actual phase delay is 2.5$\pi$ rad across all frequencies.  Although the angle could be thought of as $0.5\pi$ rad, it is not so - the transfer functions are different and a different type of control system needs to be utilized to stabilize such a transfer function.

Thus, it is necessary to represent the value in the polar form:  1 $\angle \pi$ rad and  1 $\angle 2.5\pi$ rad.

How would one evaluate the combined transfer function at a specific frequency?

E.g., 
    H(s)=s^2+s^5

at $\omega$ = 1 rad.

The result should be $1.5\angle 495 deg$.

MatLab script:

> H =tf([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],1)

H =

s^5 + s^2

Continuous-time transfer function.

> bode(H)

[image]

Note that the phase is the exact phase, not the wrapped phase.

From MatLab:

Phase Response
By default, plots display exact phase. Check Wrap phase to wrap the phase into the interval [–180º,180º).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is full of misleading information. First of all, systems which have numerator with higher degree than their denominator have no practical applications. But let's say they are theoretical systems.

> Its frequency response is 1$\angle\pi$ rad at all frequencies.

this claim does not make sense to me.

Plot its Bode diagram via `bode(tf([1 0 0],1))` in MATLAB. The response is not constant.

From Laplace to Fourier, the system is converted via replacement of $s$ by $i\omega$ (or in Electrical Engineering shown by $j\omega$).

Sys 1: $H_1(i\omega)=-\omega^2$

Sys 2: $H_2(i\omega)=i\omega^5$

The combination:

$$H(i\omega)=H_1(i\omega)+H_2(i\omega)=-\omega^2+i\omega^5$$

For $\omega=1^{~\text{rad}}$, $H(i\omega)=-1+i=1\angle135
^{~\text{deg}}$

The bode diagram in MATLAB/Octave software:

```
% pkg load control
bode(tf([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],1))
```

What the diagram shows is $135^{deg}$

I don't know how you obtained $495^{deg}$, but please not that $495^{deg}-135^{deg}=360^{deg} \equiv 0$

[image: bode diagram]

Comment: Hi Arash, apologies, made a mistake in my question.

Comment: Differentiators do exist in nature and are often used in control systems (e.g., feedforward current/torque control).  However, this does not play a role here.

Comment: Try this transfer function:  H =tf([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],1), bode(H).  The phase response is not 135 degrees.  The gist of the question is to determine how to numerically evaluate the transfer function at a specific frequency to get the correct angle.  According to your answer, the phase angle is 135 degrees, which is not correct (as per MatLab).  Thank you!

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY, please see my edit.

Comment: Hi Arash, please see my edit.  It is possible that Octave wraps the phase.  MatLab does not do so by default.  In control systems, a 495 degree phase lag requires a much different compensator than a 135 degree phase lag.  That's why the usage of complex numbers with wrapped angle is quite confusing.

Comment: @SunnyBoyNY, Many others have the same problem with phase wrap such as [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164336/is-this-a-matlab-bode-phase-plot-error) and [this](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/bode-phase-plot-reversed.61126/).

Comment: Thank you.  My original question still stands- how to get the exact phase as shown in MatLab bode plot?  That is, if using the very basic complex math and obtain 135deg, what can be done to get 495 deg?